# Is there any way for the google assistant sdk on embedded device to get the session id?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have made a home security device (raspberry pi + camera + face detection). The device is able to sense people who are at the door and store it onto a online database. I'm using dialogflow to build a conversational stream. Is there anyway for dialogflow fullfilment to know which device the request come from and retrieve it from the database (Firebase)?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to get device level identifiers.

Comment: Is there a way to send a google assistant request through text? Then, im thinking of sending the name at the push of a button

Comment: Yes you could send a text-based request, but that wouldn't send a device origin specific identifier.

Comment: I think Alexa skills have device id field. Will this be a future feature for google assistant?

Comment: I can't comment on the future